# django show last 3 char of string in admin fields

Tags: django, django-admin

database

```
| id   | salary_number |
| ---  | ------------- |
| 1    | 1042          |
```

models.py

```
class user(AbstractUser):
    salary_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)    

    def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.salary_number[-3:]}'
```

admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('salary_number[-3:]',)

def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return ['salary_number'] if obj else []
```

I would like to show Salary number: 042 in admin fields instead of 1042. Is it possible?

How can I add number 1 to the salary_number after click save new form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `'__str__'` as field:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('__str__',)
```

But this makes it unclear what the field is doing. Likely it is better to make a callable that describes that this is the last digits of the salary number:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('salary_digits',)
    
    @admin.display(description='Salary digits')
    def salary_digits(self, obj):
        if obj.salary_number is not None:
            return obj.salary_number[-3:]
```

Comment: I got error: FieldError at /admin/information/user/60/change/
Unknown field(s) (salary_digits) specified for user. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.

Comment: @TrungVu: yes, you should use `list_display`: since that are read-only properties.

Comment: I need it to show in fields, not in list_display. For example: click to user id 1, it will show me salary number 042, instead of 1042. Because number 1 means branch and I dont want to show it.

Comment: @TrungVu: then you should `exclude` it. But you can not use it in fields, since it has no *bidirectional* relation to the data: you can not write the `salary_digits` back to the object, exactly for the reason you mention.

Comment: I just add get_readonly_fields to my admin. Just want user only see, not edit.

Comment: @TrungVu: yes, you can also add the field to `readonly_fields` (not `get_readonly_fields`).